# Pin Forest Heat Sink Design and Optimization

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics, heat-transfer

I am trying to design a heat sink as part of a broader system and determine two things:

1. Given the size constraints of the system, commercially available fans, and heat dissipation requirements, is it even possible to design a heat sink to meet the requirements?
2. If it is possible, what is the optimal number and size of the pins on the heat sink?

I dug up the following formula from my old heat transfer textbook regarding pin forest heat sink design, and tried to graph number of pins as a function of pin diameter, but the result I got indicated the total cross sectional area of the pins to be larger than the area of the base of the heat sink.  I don't know if there is a different formula I should use, or if I made an error when simplifying this formula, or if it just means it is impossible to design a heat sink to meet my constraints.  Either way, I appreciate any help, and for someone to check my work.

The equation I found for a pin grid heat sink:

$$Q=[(A-N_f\pi D^2/4)+N_f\pi D(L+D/4)\eta_f]\langle Nu\rangle_D\frac{k_f}{D}(T_{s,0}-T_{f,\infty})$$

Where: 
$D$ and $N_f$ are diameter and number of fins, our independent and dependent variables, respectively
$Q=5.5W$ = Rate of heat transfer generated by system
$A=1.354*10^{-3}m^2$=base cross sectional area 
$L=.028$m=length of the pins 
$\langle Nu \rangle =$Nusselt number for semi-bounded fluid streams around a cylinder$=a_1Re_D^{a_2}Pr^{1/3}$
Where $Re_D=u_fD/v_f$
$u_f=$air velocity$=3.27m/s$ based off of a commercially available fan I found
$a_1=.683, a_2=.466$ based on a table in my textbook
$v_f=18.37*10^{-6}m^2/s$ and $PR=0.69$ and $k_f=.0287W/m-K$ for air at 330 Kelvin based off another table
$\eta_f=$ fin efficiency$=\frac{tanh(m(L+D/4))}{m(L+D/4)} $ for cylindrical fins
$m=\left( \frac{4\langle Nu\rangle_Dk_f}{D^2k_s} \right)^{1/2}$
$k_s=237.9$ for Aluminum at $330K$
$\Delta T=5K$ Requirement I am trying to meet

So when I plug everything into Wolfram I get:

$$5.5=((1.35456*10^{-3}-N_fπD^2/4)+N_fπD(.028+D/4)*\frac{tanh((.0814557(D)^{-1.534})(.028+D/4)}{(.0814557(D)^-1.534)(.028+D/4))}*(.683(178008D)^.466)*.69^{1/3}(.0287/x*(60-55))$$

or:\
5.5=((1354.56E-6-yπx^2/4)+yπx(.028+x/4)*(tanh((.0814557(x)^-1.534)(.028+x/4))/((.0814557(x)^-1.534)(.028+x/4))))*(.683(178008x)^.466)*.69^(1/3)(.0287/x*(60-55)) \
if you want the exact syntax I used.

The range of D will be $0<D<.02$ butt all of the discrete values I picked in that range, after the operation $N_f\pi D^2/4$ to determine the total cross secional area of all pins, end up with the total cross sectional area of the pins larger than $A$, which is not physically possible.

So that's where I stand.  I would really appreciate it if someone would double check my work, every step of the way I think my numbers are reasonable for hypothetical pin diameters (like $Re_D, \langle Nu\rangle_D, m, \eta$ seem reasonable for $D=.001$, though $\eta$ does seem a bit low at $1.08\%$) and confirm that if I did do the math right that this means it is impossible to design a pin grid heat sink for my situation.

I am open to using some crazy 3D printed heat sink for my application, but I don't know where to begin looking at designs.

This is my first time asking a question, apologies if it is inadequate.  I will clarify anything if its needed.